# Jackson automatically converting json date to 8 hours ahead of its time

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

In my json date is represented like this :-

```
"from":"2015-11-11T09:21:00.00Z"
```

But when it gets converted to java.sql.Timestamp it looks like this :-

```
 2015-11-11 17:21:00.0
```

My timezone is Singapore . It is 8 hours ahead of UTC timezone and coincidentally the date also gets converted to 8 hours ahead of its time.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to have the JSON output changed to Singapore timezone? Can you show some code?

Comment: Json is not the output . It is the input . I don't want the Timestamp in java to be different from json.

Comment: You should refrain from using java.sql.* classes with Jackson. See the link http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

Comment: `Z` means GMT, so everything is working as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are showing the same times, just formatted differently for the different locations.  The time you are taking in is UTC/GMT.  What you are viewing in your IDE is showing the local time stamp formating, but they are the same values and points in time.

If it really matters how it is displayed to you in the debugger you can use a Calendar object instead of a TimeStamp and set the locale value to be UTC and it will format them the same way, but again they are the same values.

> > I don't want the Timestamp in java to be different from json

It is not different, the display format is different do to the location setting but they are the same values just represented differently.

P.S.   Be aware that if your server is set to a different time zone than your work station it will show a different format as well, but it again will be the same time just represented differently.